# What do we call letters/images in printouts with less ink?

Tags: word-request, word-usage, terminology

I'm looking for a term to describe the letters (or for that matter *anything*) that are not dark *though* readable. Somewhat faded. As I just typed, I know '[faded](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fade#faded) letters' could be an option but is there any particular term for it? Another term that comes to my mind is '[hazy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/hazy) letters' but I don't think it fits. It might talk more about 'unclear' letters but not due to less ink!

Here is the image of such a printout

[image]

See the letters 'C' and 'E' in the printout.

I want to build a sentence like...

> Don't take any copies from that printer. It has very little ink left. You'll get [**faded/hazy**] printout/letters/images.

Comment: You'll get *letters with streaks in them.* Or your printout may contain *streaks.*

Comment: This [HP Printer Guide](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c02948596) may have some useful examples and different words.

Answer (score 4):

HP Printer Problem document suggests:

The procedures in this document should help with streaked or faded printouts, color or black ink not printing, documents with blurred or fuzzy text, ink streaks or smears, and other print quality problems.

Answer (score 1):

Those letters are "too faint to read" (i.e. not dark enough to be legible).

With so little ink|toner left, "you'll get a faint image".

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off approaching from the angle of “barely [legible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legible)” or “barely [discernable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discernable)”.

You could also describe the letters as *[faint](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/faint),* which is a general enough word to apply to situations where ink is not involved (and/or not the source of the issue) and descriptive enough to use on its own.

You could even combine the two and call them ***faintly legible*** in order to not only describe the letters, but also reinforce the reason that their insubstantial state matters to you.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a *faded* printout, as the term faded means that the intensity has reduced, either over time or in this case immediately from what was expected.

Comment: OP stated awareness of “faded”.

Answer (score 0):

I would call them "streaked" and would phrase the sentence like this:

> Don't take any copies from that printer. It has very little ink left.
>   You'll get a streaked printout.

or

> You'll get streaks on your letters/images.

As a side note, many printers used to have a feature that would use less ink (some still do, but it is much less common than before). That feature is called "draft mode," and was designed to not waste ink on an initial draft when changes would likely be made before reprinting the final copy. The printing was lighter, but still legible. I wouldn't have turned in a document printed in draft mode to my boss, but it was perfectly good for initial revisions or personal use.